# str.contains with multiple values & if-condition error :: Exception isn't helpful as it doesn't mention the right alternatives

Tags: python, pandas

Also NOTE: This post doesn't answer my question:
[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o?rq=1)

I am using str.contains() the following way:

```
df1['company'] = ""
search = ['Inc.','Company','Ltd','Co.']
if(df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(search), na=False)):
    df1["company"] = "Yes"
else:
    df1['company'] = "No"
```

While `df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)` works by itself, (i.e. it prints True/False values), the code written above throws a value error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is confusing is that the `df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)` does return boolean values.

NOTE: I do not want to use .all() or .any() because I want an element wise Truth/False instead of on the entire set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: _Also NOTE: This post doesn't answer my question:_ Simply stating that doesn't make it true, can you elaborate? Also, please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(search), na=False)` returns a `Series` which does not support the `if` statement because creating `Series` always returns a `Series` object, empty or not.

To answer your question;

```
# fill data-frame with True and False
df['company'] = df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)

# replace True/False with 'yes'/'no'
# Note: True == 1 and False == 0
df['company'] = df['company'].apply(lambda x: ('no', 'yes')[x])

# as a one-liner 
df['company'] = ( df1['fu'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)
                  .apply(lambda x: ('no', 'yes')[x]) )
```

Comment: _returns a Series which does not support the if statement because creating Series always returns a Series object, empty or not._ What, can you expand on what?